# Polymorphism and switch case based on instance

Tags: java, polymorphism, visitor-pattern

I have an interface called "I":

```
package org.example;

public interface I {
}
```

Pretty simple :-)

I have classes implementing this interface. They are called A, B, C, D, E, etc.

Classes A and B have specific methods, as shown below. Other classes don't.

```
public class A implements I {
    public void sayHelloFromA() {
        System.out.println("Hello from A");
    }
}

public class B implements I {
    public void sayHelloFromB() {
        System.out.println("Hello from B");
    }
}
```

My main method iterates over a list of I objects and I want to perform specific actions depending on the type of the class.

```
package org.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final A a = new A();
        final B b = new B();
        final C c = new C();

        final List<I> list = new ArrayList<I>();
        list.add(a);
        list.add(b);
        list.add(c);

        for (final I i : list) {
            sayHello(i);
        }
    }

    public static void sayHello(final A a) {
        a.sayHelloFromA();
    }

    public static void sayHello(final B b) {
        b.sayHelloFromB();
    }

    public static void sayHello(final I i) {
        System.out.println("Unsupported");
    }

}
```

Here is the problem; the output is:

```
Unsupported
Unsupported
Unsupported
```

I knew it wouldn't work, but the question is, how to make this work without using instanceof or reflexion. The trick is I can't modify the interface I (in real life, I think it's a javax.swing.tree.TreeNode).

I don't use the visitor pattern because I believe the visitor pattern is better suited when you have a fixed set of class types and you add new operations on those types. In my real life case, it's the contrary: I have only one operation and I often add new types to the list...

Comment: Use instanceof, reflection, or get the class name and switch on it.

Comment: Can you define an extra `sayHello()` method on your interface? And then, each of your classes implement it like:


    class A {
        sayHello() {
            sayHelloFromA();
        }
        sayHelloFromA() {
            // Logic goes here
        }
    }


If you can't add method to the interface, you probably could extend it

Comment: Why you can't define sayHello() in interface and implement it in each class?

Answer (score 3):

Since Java is a statically typed language, deciding which method overloading to call is done at compile time, which means you cannot call an overloaded method according to the instance's *actual* type, only by its *declared* type.

If you don't want to use reflection to find which class your instance is, but you can change A and B, you might add another interface for them to implement:

```
public interface I2 {
  void sayHello();
}
```

and have `A` and `B` implement it:

```
public class A implements I, I2 {
    public void sayHelloFromA() {
        System.out.println("Hello from A");
    }

   public void sayHello() {
       sayHelloFromA();
   }
}

public class B implements I, I2 {
    public void sayHelloFromB() {
        System.out.println("Hello from B");
    }

    public void sayHello() {
       sayHelloFromB();
   }
}
```

Comment: On a second thought, I think this is a better approach than extending from your interface. It seems more clean, since responsibilities are more clearly separated

Comment: Method *linkage* is not done at compile time.  What occurs at compile time is the selection between various possible overloaded versions of the method -- this overloading is an extension of the method *name*.  You have the choice of names `sayHello(LA;)`, `sayHello(LB;)`, and `sayHello(LI;)`.  That choice must be made by the compiler.  The actual choice of a method to execute occurs dynamically at runtime.

Comment: @HotLicks - thanks, poor choice of word, I've mended it